# Xamarin forms (ios): Runtimeexception when programmatically connecting to wifi

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Using a dependency service in Xamarin forms (in the ios part to be specific), I am trying to programmatically connect to a wifi network using this code:

```
NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfigurationManager mymanager = new NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfigurationManager(); // causing exception
NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfiguration myconf = new NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfiguration("MyWiFIName", "somePassword", false);

mymanager.ApplyConfiguration(myconf, (error) => {
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("foo");
});
```

At runtime, I am getting this exception:

```
ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException          
Can't register the class NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfigurationManager when the dynamic registrar has been linked away.
```

I followed all instructions according to this [Tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/02/15/connecting-wifi-xamarin-forms/), but I keep getting the error. All app permissions are set and no error occurs when compiling. By the way, we're talking about a "fresh" solution which has just been created, containing no other code than what I mentioned above, the interface class, a platform specific service declaration and a button to trigger the service. I found solutions on the web where I was advised to manually alter the ios.csproj file ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=vsmac)) - which did not help by the way. I also applied for permission to use NEHothelperclass at Apple, no answer yet (don't know if that is important).  What am I missing?

EDIT: 
I tried changing the linker options (ios project -> options -> ios-build -> linker) to don't link: the exception changes to:

```
ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException
Wrapper type 'NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfigurationManager' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'NEHotspotConfigurationManager'.
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the Linker Behavior to Don't Link to rule out a linker issue?

Comment: Pls see revised posting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a setting in XCode that must be enabled.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager

EDIT: Xamarin link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/?tabs=vsmac

Comment: Hm, thanks for that but all possible entitlements which are even remotely affected are all enabled and covered by my current provisioning profile. I am currently working on "Manual provisioning". May it has to be Automatic Provisioning for what I am intending to do? I would like to keep it manual and rather not enter my Apple login details into Visual Studio unless I HAVE to.

Comment: Manual provisioning should work fine.

Are you testing on a real device?

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86945

Comment: yes, real ios device which is listed in my apple developer account with wifi enabled and lots of nearby wifi networks.

Comment: Seems like it should be working then, maybe try specifying the provisioning profile explicitly instead of automatically.  May need to update your profiles from xcode.